# Do not return output

Tags: xquery, xquery-3.0

I am very new to xquery, I am trying to check if the attribute exists in the element using xquery, if exists return, return only for the b element which has id.

I tried the following:

Input

```
<a>
 <b id="id2">text</b>
 <x id="id4">text</x>
 <b>text</b>
 <b id="id5">text</b>
</a>
```

XQuery:

```
for $x in (*:a/*:b)
let $new:=
let $id := exists($x/@id)
let $c := if ($id = true()) then ($x/@id/string()) else()
return
<string key="id">{$c}</string>
return ($new)
```

But I am getting the return string for the not existence item as well. How to not return for the elements which don't  have id.

output:

```
 <string key="id">id2</string>
 <string key="id"/>
 <string key="id">id5</string>
```

Is there any easy method to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a compact solution:

```
a/b/@id/<string key="id">{ string(.) }</string>
```

Here is a more verbose alternative (there are many others):

```
for $b in *:a/*:b
let $new := 
  let $id := $b/@id/string()
  where exists($id)
  return <string key="id">{ $id }</string>
return $new
```